# IntelliJ: Does multiple runs are running independently

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I do not know how to write a proper method to test this behavior now. Please do not downvote..

I have a java class responsible for processing and adding data to multiple database right now. Each database holds the same data but processed differently (For example interpolated with different interpolation-rates).

So i run the program (clicking on the green rectangle), modify the parameters (interpolation rate) and run the program. So I have two processes running (since approx. a day.. Thats why I do not want to risk any interruption and fear that the databases are messed up).

**My question is**: does this modification apply to the process already running?

This should not be the case.. but i know that IntelliJ/AndroidStudio offers this "Instant run" feature..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't. Changing the run config does not affect the a program you've already started through that same config.

However, if you change the code and recompile it can affect an already running program. To test this, start the program running through the ide then change the code and press ctrl-f9. You should get a message saying something like "3 classes reloaded" or "failed to reload classes because change not supported by vm". (I don't have access to the exact wording)

Comment: If you change the code then the running program may well change. I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered as a bug and get fixed? If I compile a piece of code then I don't expect it to be changed during runtime...I think this will allways cause problems with integrity.. However.. The Version Control-View is not available (grayed-out). The database import is still running.. I have to think about how to proof that the databases are integer.

Comment: No, it's an extremely useful feature as it lets you make changes to your program workout having to restart it. But yes you do have to be careful about an already running program.